# hover without moving the below content

Tags: html, css, hover

I want on hover to display some items without moving the below content.
My code is the following:

```
<ul id="try" >
    <li>
      <img class="flame" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/knightsanddragons/images/f/fa/Dragons-flame.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/100?cb=20160727135656"/>
      <ul>
      <li class="one"><span>one  </span></li>
      <li class="two"><span>two  </span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
 <span>three</span>
```

and the css for hover:

```
ul#try li {display: inline-block;background: transparent;}
ul#try li:hover {background: transparent;}
ul#try li:hover ul {display: block;background: transparent;}
ul#try li ul {
  display: none;
}
ul#try li ul li { 
  display: block; 
  background: transparent;
}
```

I want to display values one and two, without moving the  `<span>three</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ul#try li ul` to `position: absolute`. Absolute positioning removes the element from the layout flow, and prevents it from changing other elements positions.

```css
ul#try li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}

ul#try li:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

ul#try li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
}

ul#try li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

ul#try li ul li {
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul id="try">
  <li>
    <img class="flame" src="https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/knightsanddragons/images/f/fa/Dragons-flame.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/100?cb=20160727135656" />
    <ul>
      <li class="one"><span>one  </span></li>
      <li class="two"><span>two  </span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<span>three</span>
```